# Onclick funciona somente no segundo click

Tags: javascript-eventos

Nesse código o Onclick só funciona após o segundo click

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>teste</title>
 <style type="text/css">
   div{
     height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  opacity: 0;
      }
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   function vai(){
     if (document.getElementById("div").style.opacity=="0") {
    document.getElementById("div").style.opacity="1"
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("div").style.opacity="0"
  }
      }
 </script>
    <p onClick="vai()">aparece</p>
    <div id="div">123</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("div").style.opacity="1" ? document.getElementById("div").style.opacity="1" : document.getElementById("div").style.opacity="0"` acho que isso resolve, troca as condições `if e else` por isto

Comment: Assim não funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você tenta verificar com um `if` se `document.getElementById("div").style.opacity` e igual a `0` vai retornar `undefined` porque não vai ter nada no inicio para resolver isso você so precisa verificar se `document.getElementById("div").style.opacity`e igUAL a `""` ou seja vazio.

Então troque a parte de seu código:

```
if (document.getElementById("div").style.opacity=="0") {
```

por

```
if (document.getElementById("div").style.opacity=="0" || document.getElementById("div").style.opacity=="") {
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>teste</title>
 <style type="text/css">
   div{
     height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    opacity: 0; 
    }
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function vai(){
     if (document.getElementById("div").style.opacity=="0" || document.getElementById("div").style.opacity=="") {
      document.getElementById("div").style.opacity = 1;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("div").style.opacity = 0;
    }
    }
 </script>
    <p onClick="vai()">aparece</p>
    <div id="div">123</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: E então porque ele aceitava após o segundo click?

Comment: Ele aceitava após o segundo click porque quando executa o código e tenta verificar com `if (document.getElementById("div").style.opacity=="0") {`ele vai retornar undefined e vai executar o código do `else` setando o valor 1 em `document.getElementById("div").style.opacity`

Comment: ah sim...Entedi..

Answer (score 1):

É o seguite... quando voce fala:

```
document.getElementById("div").style.opacity=="0")
```

na realidade, document.getElementById("div").style.opacity não esta definido. Ou seja tem valor de "" (empty string). Acho que da jogo se voce trocar o "0" por "". Ficaria assim:

```
document.getElementById("div").style.opacity == "")
```

Mas na realidade voce não quer perder a possibilidade do toggle então inclui isso o código novo com um OR no mesmo if statement

```
document.getElementById("div").style.opacity=="0" || document.getElementById("div").style.opacity==""
```

```js
function vai(){
if (document.getElementById("div").style.opacity=="0" || document.getElementById("div").style.opacity=="") 
{
    document.getElementById("div").style.opacity="1"
}
else   
{ 
    document.getElementById("div").style.opacity="0"
}
}
```

```css
div{
     height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  opacity: 0;
      }
```

```html
<p onClick="vai()">aparece</p>
<div id="div">123</div>
```

Comment: Como assim? Fiz alteração e não foi

Comment: Vou fazer um fiddle rapidinho...

Comment: ta la , faz sentido?

Comment: Entedi..mas é complicado...tem alguma outra forma mais fácil de fazer esse efeito?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `getComputedStyle()` para pegar os valores CSS de um elemento:

```js
function vai() {
 var elemento = document.getElementById('div');
 estilo = window.getComputedStyle(elemento);
 opacity = estilo.getPropertyValue('opacity');

 if (opacity=="0") {
 document.getElementById("div").style.opacity="1"
 }
 else {
 document.getElementById("div").style.opacity="0"
 }
}
```

```css
div{
     height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  opacity: 0;
      }
```

```html
<p onClick="vai()">aparece</p>
    <div id="div">123</div>
```